# How to use/enable multi-therading in Blender 2.8+

Tags: rendering, scene

So, I have an AMD Ryzen 7, it had lot's of cores and threads. So I wan to know that does Blender support Multi-therading by default or do I have to enable it. Also, is there an option to tweak this if it is supported? For

Comment: Yes, Blender supports multithreading but... not for all operations.

Answer (score 1):

It's on by default, it will use all the cores you have available. Although if you have a capable GPU you might want to use that instead.
Some things are single threaded thought (I think physics and cloth sims are single threaded, but I don't know if that changed lately).